# Translate multiple files into svf and get ths svf urn

Tags: converters, postman, autodesk-forge, urn

I am trying to convert a zip folder into svf. The zip contains  the following files :
- an .obj (3D object);
- a .mtl (links the object to its texture);
- a .tif (texture).

I used Postman's 'Request Translation (ZIP to SVF)' to get an urn. Everything seems fine until that step. I get a 64 based urn, and the request's result is "created".
But, when I try to display it with Forge viewer afterwards, I get the following error :

```
error : 9
```

According to [this](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/01/error-codes-in-view-and-data-api.html), the data would not contain any viewable data.

So I tried to use [Forge extractor](https://extract.autodesk.io/) instead, and it works perfectly, I can view my model with its texture as extractor's output.

[This post](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/09/how-to-set-references-with-inventor-files-for-view-and-data-api.html) seems to give some instructions, but I do not understand how to link the files together and register them individually for translation.

Has anyone encountered this before ?

Answer (score 0):

When calling POST Job for a `.zip` make sure to specify the `compressedUrn` and `rootFilename` attributes, something like:

```
 curl -X 'POST' -H 'Authorization: Bearer WmzXZq9MATYyfrnOFpYOE75sL5dh' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job' -d
'{
   "input": {
     "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bW9kZWxkZXJpdmF0aXZlL0E1LnppcA",
     "rootFilename": "file.obj",
     "compressedUrn": true
   },
   "output": {
      "formats": [
        {
          "type": "svf",
          "views": [
            "2d",
            "3d"
          ]
        }
      ]
   }
 }'
```

[Compressed](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/translate-zip-source-file-to-stl/) sample & [prepare for Viewer](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/prepare-file-for-viewer/) sample.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, and it does return 'success, created', but as usual, the viewer does not load the model...

Comment: seems correct... are you able to share this model for testing? if so, please send to forge.help[at]autodesk.com Please do not send any confidential information

Comment: No, I don't think I can share it.

Comment: From your original question, you said extract.autodesk.io works fine, so I would suggest review how this sample does: https://github.com/cyrillef/extract.autodesk.io/blob/838b63f1f76668081c789d9962b93a0f97d9555c/server/projects.js#L70

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get my svf urn, but I did not use the zip folder. I had to convert the files inside to another format to make it work.
Thanks for the answer though.